# SQL Server – Change the Look & Feel of the Report Manager

Tags: css, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I would like to add a background image on report manager. As in the model that was realized. [Model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tuQY.jpg) Is it possible to achieve this? In ssrs 2016 there is no more css file I think. Is it possible to do this using the branding packages?

Comment: I'm not sure what is possible with branding but I do know that it's an Enterprise only feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes you are right (we have this edition)